# Is it possible to have 2 classes with the same name and in the same package?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, overriding

I'm developing a grails app, and I need to modify a groovy class that is in a plugin, so I decided to override the class, so I have these method and class in my plugin:

```
def example = new a();
a.method();

class a {
   void method() {
      println "2";
   }
}
```

all this was Inside the plugin, so I want to create another class in the same package in my project, to change the method, but how can I set my new class to run instead the plugin's? or is it impossible?

```
class a {
   void method() {
      println "4";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to ensure that your class is on the classpath before the plugin's version.

Comment: It worked, I set first the groovy classpath and It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. It is called class shadowing. But I would advice against it most of the times. You only need to let the jvm load your class before the plugin class.